# gdal_calc in python without gdal path

Tags: python, gdal

I have the below python script which executes my raster calculation perfectly using GDAL.
However, I was wondering if there is a way to use `gdal_calc` without the path to gdal? `gdal_path = r'"C:/Program Files/GDAL"'`

```
import os

## Raster Calculator##
gdal_path = r'"C:/Program Files/GDAL"'
gdal_calc_path = os.path.join(gdal_path, 'gdal_calc.py')


# Arguements.
input_file_path = 'C:/Users/Public/try/singlebeam.tif'
input_file_path2 = 'C:/Users/Public/try/gdaltry.tif'
output_file_path = 'C:/Users/Public/try/pytry3.tif'
calc_expr = '"(A == 0) * B + (A != 0) * A"'
typeof = '"Float32"'

# Generate string of process.
gdal_calc_str = 'python {0} -A {1} -B {2} --outfile={3} --calc={4} --type={5} --hideNoData'
gdal_calc_process = gdal_calc_str.format(gdal_calc_path, input_file_path, input_file_path2,
    output_file_path, calc_expr, typeof)

# Call process.
os.system(gdal_calc_process)
```

Comment: It would have to be in the [system path](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path to the GDAL executables is on your system path, then you should be able to just call `gdal_calc.py` from anywhere, including in the `os.system()` call you're making.

[Here's a website](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) that says how to do it on Windows 10, but please search for how to do it on whatever OS you're on. Search for "Add to the system path" or similar.

Comment: once I have added it to my system path, how should I call it in my code correctly?

Comment: If it's accessible through the system path, then you don't need to prepend an explicit path and could use `gdal_calc_path =  'gdal_calc.py'` instead.